# Google Chrome - show account selection screen

Tags: google-chrome

Probably this question is widely known, but I have been unable to find an appropiate solution.

I bought a new laptop (Windows 10), and installed Google Chrome. I have several Google accounts.

**What is happenning**: when I run Chrome, it uses one of my Google accounts as default.

**What would I like**: configuring chrome to show me the account selection screen every time I run it, so that I can pick which profile will be used in the current window. I don't mind if this is achieved via a specific shortcut.

I know this is possible because I had it working on my previous laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following command starts Chrome with the profile selection window:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome --profile-directory="Guest Profile"
```

Source: [How-to Geek - How to Find Your Chrome Profile Folder on Windows, Mac, and Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/)